# Reading for char driver file in node.js?

Tags: node.js, nonblocking

I have implemented a Linux driver (beaglebone) that queries some hardware by SPI and copies the received data in a kfifo (which can get full if it is not emptied).
- This kfifo is emptied by performing reads on a char device file (let's call it /dev/foo).
- An userland program is responsible for reading the correct fifo entry size (or a multiple of it).
- The driver is started and stopped through sysfs entries.

The example C userland program reads this file in blocking mode (i.e., the read returns when data is available).

Now here's my problem:
I have a server in node.js running on the beaglebone for administration purposes and would also like to make it "collect" the data (on /dev/foo) and send it via websockets.

I don't really know how to do that, since /dev/foo is not a regular file (so fs.watch does not work), and data keeps on being available randomly on it.

Questions:
- Can I solve this problem with node's standard library (like with streams, etc?)
- Is there a node module that could solve my problem?
- Or do I have to write a node module myself (using libuv?)

Thanks for your hints on any of these points.

Comment: Since stdin is also a character device, perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12506613/893780) might be a good starting point?

Comment: Thanks. This gave me the (good) idea of opening /dev/foo as a stream (with `createReadStream`)

Answer (score 0):

I know this a bit old, but mamahuhu gave me the right idea!

Here is what I do:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var readStream = fs.createReadStream("/dev/foo");

readStream.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```