# Creating a bash wrapper in NodeJS process

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, shell, pty

I want to build a tiny script that being run should create a bash-like session (in the current bash session, where the process is created), that can be used later for some mad science (e.g. piping to browser).

I tried using [pty.js](https://github.com/chjj/pty.js), piping `stdin` to the `bash` process, and data from the bash session to the `stdout` stream:

```
var pty = require("pty.js");

var term = pty.spawn('bash', [], {
  name: 'xterm-color',
  cols: process.stdout.columns,
  rows: process.stdout.rows,
  cwd: ".",
  env: process.env
});

term.pipe(process.stdout);
process.stdin.pipe(term);

term.on("close", function () {
    process.exit();
});
```

This works, but it's very buggy:

[image]

For example, the non-characters (directional keys, tab etc) are not caught.

I also tried using `spawn`, this not being so bad, but still buggy.

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

var bash = spawn("bash");
bash.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
process.stdin.pipe(bash.stdin);
```

Is there a better solution how to create a bash wrapper in NodeJS?

Comment: Pass `bash -c command`, not `bash command`.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Why? I want to start a bash session, with streams and everything, not only passing a command.

Comment: Then I misread. Ignore me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to put the standard input into [raw mode](http://nodejs.org/api/tty.html#tty_tty_setrawmode_mode). This way all the key strokes will be reported as a data event. Otherwise you only get lines (for every press of the `return` key).

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);      

var pty = require('pty.js');

var term = pty.spawn('bash', [], {
   name: 'xterm-color',
   cols: process.stdout.columns,
   rows: process.stdout.rows,
   cwd: '.',
   env: process.env
});

term.pipe(process.stdout);
process.stdin.pipe(term);

term.on('close', function () {
    process.exit();
});
```

Maybe you also find some more experience from other in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006821/nodejs-how-to-read-keystrokes-from-stdin).

PS: Vim runs now much better :P