# Why is the JavaScript prompt working improperly?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The prompt statement in JavaScript (not Web JavaScript) is supposed to return a > prompting the user to enter a string. Here is my code:

```
var i;
while(i == i) {
    var input = prompt();
}
```

Yet this is the output:
undefined>
Is there a reason this is happening?

Comment: `prompt` doesn't exist in Node.js, only in the browser.

Comment: BTW, you probably want `while (true)`.

Comment: running your code as is results in `ReferenceError: prompt is not defined` as expected

Comment: I'm assuming it's `const { prompt } = require('inquirer')`

Comment: `i == i ` is always true

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodejs how to read keystrokes from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006821/nodejs-how-to-read-keystrokes-from-stdin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its saying undefined because there is no text inside prompt use

```
   Var input = prompt(' ');
```

It will generate a prompt with no question.

Also if you are using Node js then it will not work because prompt is part of Vanilla Js not Node js.

Answer (score 0):

Use [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html), [prompt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt), or [prompts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompts). `prompt`/`prompts` is very easy to use, readline is more advanced.