# How do i get keyboard input in plain javascript. no html and that stuff

Tags: javascript

is there a way to get keyboard input in plain javascript? I've searched it up but everything was with HTML.
I've tried this. but it says document is not defined

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) { console.log(event.keyCode)
  if (event.keyCode == 37) {
    console.log('Left was pressed');
  } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
    console.log('Right was pressed');
  }
});
```

Comment: If you are not in a browser, you do not have a document

Comment: If you are running node from the command prompt, then this is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006821/nodejs-how-to-read-keystrokes-from-stdin

Comment: Also if it is in a browser, then you have readable shortcuts : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44213036/295783